Network Services Crashed Error - Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.trendyol.com/sr?wc=70&wb=859&qt=Pantolon&st=Pantolon&os=1")

div_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "prdct-cntnr-wrppr")
links = div_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(1)

I wrote code that clicks on all A tags on a web page. However, after a certain period of time,
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51750/devtools/browser/76fcf47f-570a-4d4c-87ab-d194c78d0ddc
[10276:3872:0504/204857.309:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(599)\] Network service crashed, restarting service. I get the error

Why do you think this might be?

Do you have multiple instance of Selenium running at the same time?  For example, do you have multiple scheduled jobs that are overlapping.  I am running into the same issue, and wondering if that is the cause.
